# Transition effect causing problems with fixed position header and margin

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, css-transitions

I hope it's okay that I link to my in-progess website, since it was hard to boil it down to a JSFiddle that showed it and worked properly.

So here it is: [My website](http://www.lipedesign.dk/lipe/priser.html)

Now, if you try to scroll, when you reach a certain point, the header/menu shrinks down, and become fixed at the top, so that it is always visible.
Now, the problem, as you might see, is that the "banner" region hops up a nudge, when the header becomes fixed. As such, it is the correct distance, when the transition effect has ended. But since the "banner" region doesn't have a transition, it's hops up instant, which makes it not great.

My problem is, that if I give that "banner" region a transition effect, it starts (When you are at the top) with a margin-top of 0px. Now, when the header becomes fixed, I have to account for that not taking up space so to speak. That I can do by giving the "banner" region, when the transition occurs, a margin-top of 61px. The problem is, as you might can see, that if I give that a transition, it will go from margin-top 0px to 61px, which means that it will start way closer to the top, and the go down to the right position. So actually, the jump it makes now, will become even larger in the beginning, that it is now.

THe JS I use for the fixed position header is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var s = $("header");
        var p = $('.pageWrapper');
        var pos = s.position();                    
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
                p.addClass("stick");
            } else {
                p.removeClass("stick"); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The CSS for the header and banner region is:

```
header {
    max-width:1920px;
    width:100%;
    height:91px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    background:#ffffff;
    z-index:9999;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;

}

.stick header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 2px -2px #b32f01;
    z-index:9999;
    height:61px;
    -webkit-transition: height position 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height position 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height position 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height position 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: height position 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.stick .bannerContentWrapper {
    margin-top: 61px;
}

.stick ul.nav li a {
    padding-top:30px;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.stick .logo img {
    padding-top:7px;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.top {
    max-width:960px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    display:table;
    background:#ffffff;
}

.logo {
    display:table-cell;
    width:30%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo img {
    padding-top:37px;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

ul.nav li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:60px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    border-top:3px white solid;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#333333;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: padding 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.bannerContentWrapper {

    background-image:url('../images/orange-bg.jpg');
    background-position:center;
    max-width:1920px;
    width:100%;
    height:482px;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

So yeah, basically, when I reach a certain point in the scroll motion, it turns on the "stick" CSS

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
.stick .logo img
```

rules from your css, and change your jQuery code to include this:

```
if (windowpos >= pos.top) {

  p.addClass("stick");

  $( ".logo img" ).animate({
    paddingTop: "7px"
  }, 400);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to do anything for me :/